# how can I call my method child to inside my function?

Tags: python

I am trying to send my src_path file to my function`lazy_ass`, and then back to `on_created` but I got  `TypeError: lazy_ass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'` , how can I improve it to call like this?

```
class updater(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, src_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.last_modified = datetime.now()
        self.__src_path = src_path
        self.__event_observer = Observer()

    def on_created(self, event):
        if datetime.now() - self.last_modified < timedelta(seconds=1):
            return
        else:
            self.last_modified = datetime.now()
            print(f"hey, {event.src_path} has been created!")
            self.lazy_ass()


    def lazy_ass(self, event):
            print(f"github {event.src_path}!")
```

Comment: You seem to have several methods, but I don't see any class.

Comment: yes, they are inside a class called `updater`

Answer (score 0):

You should delete your `event` parameter if you are not using it, however, if you want it to be a placeholder (eg. for future use), you can try `def lazy_ass(self, event=None):` (See document about default argument [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/))

Answer (score 0):

You've called `self.lazy_ass()` inside instance method `on_created`. So that `lazy_ass` can access all instance properties, so your function will look like this:

```py
def lazy_ass(self):
    print(f"github {self.__src_path}!")
```

This code removed `event` because you're not passed any event when you call `self.lazy_ass()` that lead you to this error: `TypeError: lazy_ass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`. Secondly, you can access to `__src_path` (which you set from `__init__` method) inside `lazy_ass` method.